# Read Multiples files name using glob and read content of every file

Tags: python

Hi I wrote a simple program to read multiples files from a folder and print 
content of each file but when I run this program I noticed that there is unlimited blank line loop is going on. I know each files have not more then 50-70 lines. Am I missing something in this code?

```
import glob
a=open('content.txt','w')
filesname=glob.glob('*.txt')
for line in filesname:
    with open(line) as con:
        for l in con:
             print l
             a.write(l+'\n')
a.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file for reading, and then read the file object.  Assuming you are trying to aggregate the data from all files into one file, try this:

```
import glob
a=open('content.txt','w')
filesname=glob.glob('*.txt')
for line in filesname:
    with open(line,"r") as con:
        fileData=con.read()
        a.write(fileData+'\n')
a.close()
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Try open(line).read() to access the string in the files

Answer (score 1):

By `unlimited blank line loop` do you mean the blank line after every line? That can be fixed by removed `+\n` and placing it outside the for loop. Also you don't need to write line by line to file. You can write an entire file. The following code seems to be working fine on my machine.

```
import glob
a=open('content.txt','w')
filesname=glob.glob('*.txt')
for line in filesname:
    with open(line) as con:
        text = con.read()
        print(text)
        a.write(text)
        a.write('\n')
a.close()
```

Comment: Actually i didn't mean that it's really have unlimited blank line loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found my ans of my question. Here Is my code:-

```
import glob
a=open('content.txt','w')
filesname=glob.glob('*.txt')
for line in filesname:
     with open(line) as con:
          for l in con:
                l=l.strip()
                if l!="":
                     print l
                     a.write(a+'\n')
a.close()
```